# Conditionally expand row in kendo grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In my Kendo grid, I am trying to check if one of my column fields is true or false. If it is true, row should be expanded, if it is false, row should stay collapsed. My code definition for column is:

```
{
  field: "Comment",
  title: txt.TXT_COMMENT,
  template: '<input type="checkbox" #= Comment ? "checked" : "" # disabled="false" ></input>',
},
```

My code condition in dataBound for checking if there is data:

```
dataBound: function (e) {
  var data = this.dataItem;
  if (data.Comment == 1) {
    this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row"));
  }
  f_OnDataBound(e);
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: At first sight, your databound function won't work because `this` won't have `dataItem`. Can you produce a fiddle that illustrates your problem? I can see that can't work but it's too few code for me to be able to help

Comment: my code is unfortunately too big and gets data from local database :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right direction by using the databound event. What you need to do after it is, iterating through all the rows and check for a specific model property and expand, or not, that specific row.

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");       
var data = grid.dataSource.data();
var len = data.length;

for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var row = data[i];
    if(row.Comment == '1') { // checks for the value of the Comment property
        grid.expandRow("tr[data-uid='" + row.uid + "']"); // expands the row with the specific uid
    }
}
```

I tested this and works perfectly. I can't know what's on the `Comment` propery though, that's up to you to control and adapt the javascript function if needed.

**EDIT**

I have created [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5MU4r/169/) that demonstrates the above strategy. In the example the `dataBound` function looks for the property "name" and expands the row if it is "Sally"

Comment: there is only one little problem, it stops on the first result, expands only first row that contains comment, how can I deal with it?

Comment: What do you mean, "stops on the first result"? Does it only expand the first row where `Comment == 1` and not the others? Weird, there's no logical reason for that. Here's another [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5MU4r/170/) that shows it works perfectly for any amount of records. It must be something else then

Comment: can we continue this discussion shortly in [chat] ?

Comment: can you invite me please? i cannot invite you

Comment: [Let us continue here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83178/js-conditionally-expand-row-in-kendo-grid)